# About validating a kernel

Tags: machine-learning

I've a test in a few days and I've a few issues with some of the subjects.

Let's start with kernels, basically I understood that a kernel needs to be positive semidefinite and symmetric in order to be valid. Is that enough? For example the following kernel, kernel(x,y) = 2 * k1(x,y) for some k1 which is a valid kernel. Is that valid? My question is how can I distinguish between a valid kernel and a nonvalid kernel if I'm given a kernel in the test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three requirements to apply Mercer's theorem:

1. K is continuous
2. K is symmetric
3. K is positive semidefinite

If you have these three properties, you have a valid kernel.

> For example the following kernel, kernel(x,y) = 2 * k1(x,y) for some k1 which is a valid kernel. Is that valid?

Yes, it is easy to show that given proper kernels K1, K2:

1. aK1, for any a>0
2. K1 + K2

are valid kernels, thus you also get that for any a, b > 0 aK1 + bK2 is a valid kernel.

> My question is how can I distinguish between a valid kernel and a nonvalid kernel if I'm given a kernel in the test ?

There is no magic way. The problem is really hard for generic functions. Thus on the test I would expect either non-kernels which are easy to falsify (do not have a property of typical dot product), or valid kernels, which are possible to prove are valid through either Mercer's theorem, or through construction.

In particular, another way of proving something is a kernel is by explicitely finding phi, since by definition for every kernel K there exists phi such that

```
K(x,y) = <phi(x), phi(y)>
```

so if you can find phi that has this property - you prove that K is a kernel.

For example - let K be a graph kernel, defined as `K(G1, G2) = amount of vertices shared by G1 and G2`. It is easy to show that if we take `phi(G) = one hot encoding of the vertices in G`, then

```
K(G1,G2) = <phi(G1), phi(G2)>
```